# Excel 2016 Macro Unable to Find File : Runtime Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am running into issues while attempting to open an additional Excel file using VBA in Excel 2016. It matters not whether the file is in the same directory. I am thinking it has something to do with a default setting in Excel 2016 that is blocking the search? The Macro functioned in Excel 2010.

```
Private Sub CommmandButton_Click()
Dim source As String
Dim temp As Workbook

source = InputBox("Enter source")

Set temp = Workbooks.Open(source)

end sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are entering the path into the inputbox correctly, it should be of the form of `C:\Folder\File.xlsx`

Comment: Maybe you could use a [FileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel) instead of an InputBox?

Comment: Are you really typing the full file path into an input box? Why not use something like `Application.Getopenfilename` instead?

Comment: @VincentG is right. Don't make users type this in. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-filedialog-property-excel

Comment: Thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example solution using the `FileDialog` object

```
Private Sub CommmandButton_Click()
    Dim fDialog As FileDialog, _
        wb      As Excel.Workbook
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select a file"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        .Filters.Clear
        ' Prevent Error by specifying that the user must use an excel file
        .Filters.Add "Excel files", "*.xlsx,*.xls,*.xlsm"
    End With
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
       Set wb = Excel.Workbooks.Open(fDialog.SelectedItems(1))
    Else 
        End  ' Cleanly exit the Macro if the user cancels
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allowing users to do more than point and click.  This is asking for trouble.  Instead:

```
Private Sub CommmandButton_Click()
Dim source As String
Dim temp As Workbook

source = Application.GetOpenFilename()

Set temp = Workbooks.Open(source)

end sub
```

This code can be further enhanced to:
    1. pre-select the initial path
    2. set the file-type(s)
    3. give guidance
    4. gracefully handle cancellations

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect!